# Muti-hot encoding vs Label-Encoding

Tags: encoding

I am learning about different input-vector representations for Neural Networks

One of the alternatives to sparse One-Hot encoded vector is the Multi-Hot encoding.

Do I understand correctly that a traditional binary approach to counting numbers is exactly what the Multi-Hot is?  We can imagine a byte as a vector of 8 components, and each entry is either 0 or 1.0

**Second part of the question:**

I would like to use Multi-Hot encoding to express up to 255 possible input values. If I use the binary-approach, will this be identical to Label-encoding? In a sense that network will figure out that 00000010 is "superior" to 00000001, that there is a "strong correlation and precedence"?

Or is it less exaggerated? For example, in Label-encoding, I could merely use 1 input neuron, just with a varied strength of 0 to 255, much like an enum. There the effect would be really exaggerated, as it presents a really obvious precedence of value $A$ over value $A-1$

This means I can't use it for 255 distinct categories (or for relatively unrelated categories)

Is the effect as bad in Multi-Hot encoding, in particular in a binary approach?

---

If it's the same as Label-Encoding (which only uses 1 input neuron), why would people ever consider Multi-hot, bloating the dimension of the input-vector?

[This post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/37218/43077) points out we can use multi-hot when the input should contain $N$ concatenated one-hot vectors. For example to represent $N$ entities each of which can belong to $Z$ distinct categories.  Is there also another use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of binary encoding as a compromise between label encoding and one-hot encoding. For distinct categories, label encoding introduces a false linear order that brings a lot of noise into the model (category 1 < category 2 < category 3....) . Binary encoding introduces false additive relationships between the categories (e.g. category 4 + category 1 = category 5 or 100 + 001 = 101) but fewer of them.

Therefore, binary will usually work better than label encoding, however only one-hot encoding will usually preserve the full information in the data.

Unless your algorithm (or computing power) is limited in the number of categories it can handle, one-hot encoding will be preferred over other encoding schemes. If you are limited, mean encoding is a powerful alternative because it transform a categorical feature into a numeric one (giving you the minimal number of inputs) while preserving the most important information in the data.

[Mean encoding replaces every category with its target mean. The mean encodings need to be constructed carefully on a separate dataset to avoid data leakage. If you want to reduce your input dimensions as much as possible, this can be helpful. Mean encoding can also be helpful as an *additional* feature and is very popular on Kaggle to squeeze out some extra performance. This is also known as *target* encoding or *likelihood* encoding.]

Comment: Good answer. I also want to add for future readers to remember that one-hot input vector isn't as wasteful (in execution performance) as it might seem at the first glance. There is no need to pass the input through a proper weight-matrix in first layer. That's because one-hot input vector always has only 1 non-zero entry. Two words: Embedding Matrix. They allow to save speed. It's done by pre-computing the incoming values in all neurons of our first layer, given some one-hot index. Then, we simply take an appropriate row from our matrix, and activate it. (No need for expensive dot-products)

Comment: Also, there is no need to waste memory by having a one-hot vector that has 1000 zeros and just one entry as 1.0;  Instead we can just store it as an index.  We then can use such an index to get an appropriate entry in the embedding matrix

Comment: that's correct. sorry, my answer wasn't specific to modern frameworks for neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I understand correctly that a traditional binary approach to counting numbers is exactly what the Multi-Hot is? We can imagine a byte as a vector of 8 components, and each entry is either 0 or 1.0

I strongly believe so.

> This means I can't use it for 255 distinct categories (or for relatively unrelated categories)
>
> Is the effect as bad in Multi-Hot encoding, in particular in a binary approach?

I found a pretty interesting answer.  It seems that binary can actually be used with classification tasks really well!
Have a look at the table on the last page of paper ["A Comparative Study of Categorical Variable Encoding Techniques for Neural Network Classifiers"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kedar_Potdar/publication/320465713_A_Comparative_Study_of_Categorical_Variable_Encoding_Techniques_for_Neural_Network_Classifiers/links/59e6f9554585151e5465859c/A-Comparative-Study-of-Categorical-Variable-Encoding-Techniques-for-Neural-Network-Classifiers.pdf) 2017

[image]

This would mean we can save the number of input neurons BY AN INCREDIBLE AMOUNT, instead of using traditional one-hot encoding.

Personally, I can get it intuitively: Label-encoding tells us to set a neuron with different values: 1,2,3,4...  It's really easy for the network to linearly-interpolate from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3, by using fractions. Thus, there is a really strong precidence between such input values, and the network will easily pick up on that. So we can't use Label-encoding for categories.

Contrary to that, Binary encoding exhibits a more "integer-like" behavior. In other words, it's not as blatantly evident how to linearly interpolate from 1 to 2 in binary form (from 0001 to 0010), which resembles one-hot approach too :)

Comment: This study is not very good... all the variables are ordinal and have at most 4 levels (which can be represented in order(!) as 00,01,10,11 from which it is easy to infer the ordinal relationship, however this becomes impossible if you have more many levels). I don't think you can draw any conclusions about encoding schemes for bigger, categorical (not necessarily ordinal) data. For big categorical data with many levels, a NN with binary encoding will not outperform a NN with one-hot encoding if you make it big enough and train it appropriately.

Comment: Ah, good point! :( But I don't hope to outperform one-hot, I merely wish it would be as good as one-hot